# Reading continuously the console output of a background c programme , using a python code

Tags: python, c, parsing, ctypes

I am on linux system ,I have a c code which is outputting data from a continuous calculation,
I want to run this code in background and parse this data from a python code. Python code will be the one in the foreground.
I was thinking something like this  :

```
>mycode  &
>python3 mypythoncode
```

(">" is the linux prompt)
but is this approach fine? what will be the corresponding code for the same for python code?

Comment: Did you mean `mycode | python3 mypythoncode` there? `&` is for a background job, `|` is for feeding output from one program into another as its input.

Comment: @Erwin yes I meant this, but mycode pukes lot of data continously..

Answer (score 2):

OK i figured it out :

### My c code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  while(1)
          printf("hello World from c \n");
         return 0;
}
```

### My Python code

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print("from Python",line)
    pass
```

Output :

```
command :  ./p | python t.py



from Python hello World from c

from Python hello World from c

from Python hello World from c
```